# Conditional distribution under Random Unitary Transformation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ be random unitary matrices. Is the following relation satisfied:
\begin{align}
p(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{x})=p(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{B}\mathbf{x}),
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are arbitrary random vectors and p(.|.) is the conditional distribution.

Comment: Is there any extra information about $p$? As is, the answer is "no". For example, I can think of a trivial distribution: $p(\mathbf{y}) = 1$ if and only if $\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{y_0}$. Then the distribution does not depend on $\mathbf{x}$, and $p(\mathbf{Ay_0}) = 0$ almost surely.

Comment: Are you asking $\mathbb{P}(Y = y | X = x) = \mathbb{P}(AY = Ay | BX = Bx)$?

Comment: Gábor Pálovics: Yes.

Comment: In my problem there is a linear relation between $\mathbf{y}$ and $\mathbf{x}$. But I don't think it matters.

Comment: This relationship is clearly true for deterministic $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$. But what about random matrices?